# search for string wth one question mark inside in python

Tags: python, string, search

I have a problem with searching strings with one questionmark inside:
From an very big HTML-Frame i want to extract a number: **A3949228**

Therefore i search for the matching beginning of the line: **<input id="grdSuchErgebnis_ct**

HTML-Frame: (saved in variable: Data[0])

```
<input id="grdSuchErgebnis_ctl23_chkSelect" type="checkbox" name="grdSuchErgebnis$ctl23$chkSelect" onclick="javascript:SelectAnlage(&#39;**A3949228**&#39;);" />
```

The line (with the same beginning string) occures may times and i need to put the line with the stringin a new list.

My code so far:

```
List = []
for i in range(len(Data[0])): 
    if (Data[0][i].find("""<input id="grdSuchErgebnis_ct""") != -1):
        List.append(i)
```

How do i have to define the search-string to find the substring with " in the middle??
(Python 3.7)

THANKS!!!!

Comment: You need to place an escape character before the nested quote character: `"<input id=\"grdSuchErgebnis_ct"`

Comment: i just tried, it does not work this way :-(

Comment: you could use beautifulsoup4 to find that element text and then do `text.split('**')[1]` assuming there is only one point with `**` in the element, kinda hacky and makes me uncomfortalbe inside